# how to create letter "s" through nodes?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, shaders, procedural

i create part by part . like top of the s first than middle part of s.

it doesn't look very professional.

is there any better way to do it?

[letter A](https://youtu.be/gS6rDmbDGTw)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a half circle by attaching a colorramp to a spherical gradient and removing the bottom half greater than math.

[image: half circle]

Make these nodes into a group. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>

Create a square by clamping X and Y coordinates to [-1, 1]

[image: block]

Rotate the items with vector math operations or mapping nodes.
Squash the square into a rectangle and place it in the center. Use the half circles for top and bottom.

[image: S]

We can improve this setup by using a Radial Gradient and plug it into a colorramp to control the half circle, then we can increase the angle.

[image: S]

[image]

Comment: Thanks.. .i thought maybe there is a better way to do it...like sending rays from the centre to create top part and than mirrored it...i don't know . .maybe it doesn't make sense..